# JS script works on Mac but not Windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm working with a table with scrollable header (left header and top header). I have a script which allows me to do such thing, but, the script seem to work only on Mac and on Windows seem to crash. Keep in mind that I'm working on google Chrome and both OS are running with it so i can test it on both OS.

The script:

```
function scrollingDiv(scroll, reaction, direction){
   $(scroll).scroll(function(e) {
       if (direction == 'horizontal') {
           $(reaction).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
       } else {
           $(reaction).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
       }
   });
```

}

Comment: did you try checking if the function receives the proper parameters under windows?

Comment: No, i didn't, but it should since the only way to execute this function is scrollingDiv(div1, div2, '');
scrollingDiv(div2, div1, '');

scrollingDiv(topDiv, div2, 'horizontal');
scrollingDiv(div2, topDiv, 'horizontal');

Comment: That is weird. maybe just to be sure, check if the scroll and reaction parameter has the proper values. Did you encounter any error or it just straight up not working?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It just crashes, no error is shown in console, not a single error...

Comment: Ok, wait... i'll make a table with top header and left header, if you're working on windows, then you'll be able to see it

Comment: ok it would help if you can post your code here so that we could test

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xbaq5ksk/52/

Comment: There... I tried to make it work as my original table, but it does the job... you can see it should be able to scroll up and down, the top header i wasn't able to make it look like the one i'm working, but if the scroll left works, then the scroll top will aswell...

Comment: It is working on my side, and im using chrome and on windows. I think the problem is else where, try triggering the script manually and see if it will work. (e.g. call on console $(reaction).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft()); with proper values)

Comment: It works, but it goes very slow, it barely moves

Comment: So this current problem is already solved? if so, i think for that one you need to create a new question because its a different matter